# Check In / Check Out Visual Studion Team project with Git repository

Tags: git, visual-studio, azure-devops

I'm working in Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise.  I have a solution that is shared between myself and one other person.  We are both going to be building this application out, so we have to be sure not to overwrite each other's changes.

Using the Azure DevOps, we've set up a Git repository and have successfully connected to it within our respective Visual Studio installs.  We can both update files and then Commit and Push them back to the server without any problem.

Our issue though is when one of us is working in a file and the other tries to open the same file, we are not alerted that it is checked out already.  We need someway to ensure we're not overwriting each others work.

Can check in / check out be set up in Visual Studio just like we've done in our Dreamweaver install?  What would be the steps to getting that in place?

Comment: Let git do its work. When you push and there are conflicting changes you can revision the changes and choose the correct version or merge the two together

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it is possible that [Team Found Version Control (TFVC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/comparison-git-tfvc?view=vsts) is a better version control option within Azure DevOps for your team.  It might have [check out options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/tfvc/check-out-edit-files?view=vsts) more similar to what you are familiar with.

You can select this version control option when creating a new project or when adding a new repo.